# How to load a variable and be able to add to it?

Tags: javascript

I have a button to save a variable and one to load a variable. The save button works good and the load but when i run my function to add 1 to the variable, it adds another number to the side instead of adding it to the number. Here's my code:

```
<button onClick="save();" style="color:black;">Save Money</button>
<button onClick="load();" style="color:black;">Load Money</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var money = 0;

  function updateClickCount() {
    document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = money;
  };
</script>

<script>
  function save() {
    localStorage.setItem('cash', money);
  }

  function load() {
    cash = localStorage.getItem('cash');
    money = cash

    updateClickCount();
  }
</script>

<script>
  function moneyy() {
    money += 1;
    updateClickCount();

  }
</script>

<p>
  <div class="div" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: black; border: 0px;"></div>MONEY: $
  <div class="div" id="clickCount"></div>
</p>

<button type="button" class="textButton" onClick="setTimeout(moneyy, 1000);" id="push">Search Small Caravan</button>
```

Thanks for any help, please i really want people to be able to save their game! Also tips welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You must parse the variable to be a number or the `+` operator will be string concatenation with type coercion (the number `1` will be coerced to the string numeral `"1"`):

```
money = parseInt(money, 10) + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. I just replaced the + 1 with a zero. Thank you!

Comment: @TarasLytvynchuk It's general practice to accept the answer which worked for you so that others know it was your solution. It also helps the person who answered the question gain reputation for doing a good job.

Comment: @TarasLytvynchuk I'm pleased I could help you out. Now you can accept the answer. Thank you very much.